# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, ros, assertions

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. Solving the Computer Vision problem of recognising red circles as of now. Since by nature, the drone is not stable (as there is an internal PID controller stabilising the drone) and due to lighting conditions, the drone often detects the same circle but in a very unstable way. To tackle this problem, comments on [this][1] question suggested that I try video stabilization.

### Error

This is the error I am currently looking at:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in gemm, file
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp,
line 900 terminate called after throwing an instance of
'cv::Exception'   what(): 
/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:900:
error: (-215) a_size.width == len in function gemm
```

### Code

```
class Tracker {

    cv::Mat prevGray;
    vector<cv::Point2f> trackedFeatures;

    void processImage(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg) {

        // ROS declarations 
        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

        // Function Initializations
        if (freshStart == true) {
            cv::Mat rightTransform = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
        }
        cv::Mat gray; 
        cv::Mat copy_img;
        vector<cv::Point2f> corners;

        try { 
             cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, 
                        sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
        } 
        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
            ROS_INFO("cv_bridge exception");
            return;
        }

        copy_img = cv_ptr->image;
        cv::cvtColor(cv_ptr->image, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        if (trackedFeatures.size() < 200) {
            cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,corners,200,0.01,10);
            for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); ++i) {
                trackedFeatures.push_back(corners[i]);
            }
        }

        if (!prevGray.empty()) {
            vector<uchar> status;
            vector<float> errors; 

            calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevGray, gray, trackedFeatures, corners,
                    status, errors, Size(10,10));

            if (countNonZero(status) < status.size() * 0.8) {
                cout << "cataclysmic error\n";
                rigidTransform = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
                trackedFeatures.clear();
                prevGray.release();
                freshStart = true;
                return;
            } else {
                freshStart = false;
            }

            cv::Mat_<float> newRigidTransform = estimateRigidTransform(
                    trackedFeatures, corners, false);
            cv::Mat_<float> nrt33 = cv::Mat_<float>::eye(3,3);
            newRigidTransform.copyTo(nrt33.rowRange(0,2));
            rigidTransform *= nrt33;

            trackedFeatures.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < status.size(); ++i) {
                if (status[i]) {
                    trackedFeatures.push_back(corners[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Debugging to see the tracked features as of now
        for (int i = 0; i < trackedFeatures.size(); ++i) {
            circle(cv_ptr->image, trackedFeatures[i], 3, Scalar(0,0,255), 
                CV_FILLED);
        }

        imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW, cv_ptr->image); 
        cv::waitKey(3);

        gray.copyTo(prevGray);
    }
};
```

Now I know the error lies in the statement `gray.copyTo(prevGray)`. This is due to the fact that I get no errors when I comment this out.

### Overall Structure of the Program

```
class Tracker {

    // The ROS declarations 
    ...

    // Internal Declarations
    ...

    public:
    bool freshStart;
    Mat_<float> rigidTransform;
    ...

    Tracker():it_(nh1_) {
        image_sub_ = it_.subscribe("/ardrone/bottom/image_raw", 1,
                                        &Tracker::processImage, this);
        image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/stabImage", 1);

        cv::namedWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
    }

    ~Tracker() {
        cv::destroyWindow(OPENCV_WINDOW);
    }

    void processImage(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg) {
    ...
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "video_stabilizer");
  Tracker tr;
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happened to the indentation? That code's all over the place :(

Comment: Which statement in that function does that exception fire from (use a debugger)? I presume you call this function multiple times, and the exception happens on the second call (i.e. when `!prevGray.empty()`) ?

Comment: @DanMašek I'm not sure what happened to the indentation. It looks okay from my side. Let me run this through `gdb`. Stepping through each function call is going to be slightly annoying.

Comment: @DanMašek Doesn't seem like I can get `gdb` running on this unfortunately. Any suggestions how I could go ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a matmul issue. Where do you initialize `rigidTransform`?

I think instead of the line:

```
cv::Mat rightTransform = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
```

you need:

```
rigidTransform = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32FC1);
```

The problem does not happen when you comment out `gray.copyTo(prevGray)` because without it the loop if `if (!prevGray.empty())` does not run.

Comment: I have edited the question to indicate the full structure of the program.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the bug that I was facing from a few days. Thanks for solving it. For some reason, `gdb` and therefore by extension, `valgrind` are not working on my Raspberry Pi

Comment: But now I get the error:

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedSize()) in release, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2578
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:2578: error: (-215) !fixedSize() in function release`

Comment: I think the problem comes from  `newRigidTransform.copyTo(nrt33.rowRange(0,2));` `estimateRigidTransform` could return an empty matrix so you need to check for this case.