# Why isn't gdb working for me

Tags: c++, cmake, gdb, ros, tui

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. Solving the Computer Vision problem of recognising red circles as of now.

### Specific Problem

I am constantly getting the error I get in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145106/opencv-error-assertion-failed-a-size-width-len) question. To help me solve this, I have decided to use gdb. However, the command `rosrun --prefix 'gdb run --args' zlab_drone vdstab` does not seem to be working for me. `zlab_drone` is the name of the package and `vdstab` is the name of the executable I am trying to run. Since this is inside a ROS environment, I have grabbed the syntax from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB), and used the suggestions in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/222530/running-rosrun-with-gdb/).

When I invoke this command, even with `tui`, I get a `SIGSEGV` and when I invoke `list` inside `gdb` itself, the program does not stay at a particular point and keeps listing a different line till it is out of range. This is quite a weird issue.

I managed to make it work without this issue earlier by using a different command, I reckon. I just cannot remember how I made it work last time.

Comment: Are you missing `-ex` ? Should the command be `rosrun --prefix 'gdb -ex run --args' zlab_drone vdstab` ?

Comment: @ks1322 I have already tried that to no avail.

Comment: Does gdb or tui or your node get the SIGSEGV? Did you do a clean build? Did you make sure you have the appropriate build setup so symbols are available? Please run gdb manually, without `rosrun` and `tui`, presumably via `gdb devel/lib/zlab_drone/vdstab` (or `gdb install/lib...`). Then type `run` (and after gdb stops, try `bt`) and post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb/+bug/1576432) exclusive bug that relates to Raspberry Pi's solely. Basically the solution involves, as quoted by Peter Bennet:

> There is a workaround. Start the program, then from another command
>   prompt or from an ssh remote login, use gdp -p xxxxx where xxxxx is
>   the process number. This works without crashing. If you need to debug
>   something that happens before you can get in from another command
>   prompt, add to the program a command that stops process at the
>   beginning of main, for example a call to gets, which will wait for you
>   to press enter before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) you mentioned, it states clear that you should use either :

```
launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args" : run your node in a gdb in a separate xterm window, manually type run to start it
```

or :

```
launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args" : run your node in gdb in the same xterm as your launch without having to type run to start it
```

So, it really looks like you missed an **-ex** as @ks1322 suggeseted in the comments or just type **run** to start the debug process.

Comment: I have tried this already, it does not work. I face the same problems that I was facing in the question above.